# Ошибка сборки проекта в Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, build

Вернулся к старому проекту. Обновил Gradle, однако собрать проект так и не удалось.

> C:\Users\User\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3b8d18d2964d8986ee9732c59bb2294b\constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2\res\values\values.xml:268:5-4347: AAPT: error: resource attr/flow_horizontalSeparator (aka com.user.app:attr/flow_horizontalSeparator) not found.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Удалите папки .idea, .gradle,build. В разметках разберитесь с вашими layout-ми скорее всего вы подтянули ConstaraintLayout из androidx, а в в разметке у вас стоит вариант из android

Comment: В проекте не используется `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: Читайте внимательно ошибку, у вас чёрным по желтому написано: constraintlayout-2.0.0-beta2, ищите может в сторонних библиотеках. И ещё одно, как ваариант вернуться к стабильной версии, но во второй версии появилось много плюшек, и это тоже можетбыть проблемой. Версия здесь: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/constraintlayout

Answer (score 0):

А вот файл horizontalSeparator может переименовать в > horizontal_separator  ну чтобы не было заглавных букв. Надеюсь сработает